# Query Overpass turbo by latitude longitude

Tags: gps, openstreetmap, overpass-api

How do I ask overpass turbo to give me the way tags corresponding to a set of latitude longitude coordinates?

thanks!

This is what i tried so far:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(way(around:1.0,52.004940, 4.369381));
(._;>;);
out tags;
```

But there are 2 problems here.
1. I get a list of different nodes and ways. But i actually only want the way where there is a speed limit given
2. I don't know how to write a query for a whole list of coordinates. Not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: @mmd please see my edited question.

Comment: 1. you need to use a tag filer: [maxspeed] and add that to your way query: `way(around:1.0,52.004940, 4.369381)[maxspeed]`.  2. no, that's no possible - you need several way(around:...) queries and get the union of all queries. Better would be to use a larger radius and issue fewer queries.

Comment: it still gives me the nodes. But it did filter out the ways without maxspeed tag. So I guess i need to somehow filter out the "type" = "node". Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove that `(._;>;);` part.

Comment: Works! Thanks mmd!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how the query should look like to return ways with maxspeed tags at a given location with 1m radius:

```
way[maxspeed](around:1.0,52.004940, 4.369381);
out tags;
```